# React useEffect invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, setstate

I'm new to React, and I'm having problem with setState and useEffect.

- I want to make *findWinner()* to wait until *setHand()* is done
- I've found that useEffect() can help this but it shows invalid hook call (I want to know why)

This is my code snippet.

```
    const [hand, setHand] = useState({myhand:-1, comhand:-1})

    function setWinner(h){
        useEffect(() => {
            findWinner(hand.myhand, hand.comhand)
        }, [hand]);

        setHand({myhand:h, comhand:Math.floor(Math.random()*10)%5});

    }
```

Comment: you cannot use useEffect in a function, see the docs

Answer (score 2):

You want the `useEffect` hook outside of `setWinner`. You cannot use it inside a function, but will be automatically called whenever the value of `hand` changes (as you have written it in the dependency array in the form of `[hand]`).

So effectively, whenever `setHand` is called, `useEffect(() => {...}, [hand])` will also be called.

```js
const [hand, setHand] = useState({myhand: -1, comhand: -1});

useEffect(() => {
  findWinner(hand.myhand, hand.comhand);
}, [hand])

function setWinner(h) {
  setHand({myhand:h, comhand:Math.floor(Math.random()*10)%5})
}
```

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? When i put 'console.log(hand.myhand, hand.comhand)' in the last line of setWinner(), it always shows the previous one, not the changed one . Is this because console.log takes more time than useEffect?

Comment: Updating the state is asynchronous. thats why u see old value in the console.log in the function.. if you log it outside the function. then it will show the updated value..

Comment: `setHand` takes "more time" than `console.log`. When you do `setHand`, it updates the values of `hand` asynchronously and allows the next line to execute without blocking.